# Project name doesnt show in my eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

When I was using adt16 in my eclipse

```
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

everything was ok, but when I use adt 20 then in the package explorer it doesnt show the project names, the projects are being separated by their packages and launcher java class names like

```
com.pack.project.javaclass
```

so this is irritating, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I think as the name goes "Package Explorer", it tells you the package name and that is what it is meant to be. rite?

Comment: but then in adt16 was wrong? btw there is also an option called project explorer, that is also showing this

Comment: You want to see it in folder structure instead of packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you use the same workspace?
sometimes it occur to me to when I'm trying to change the path of the source folder
but you can change the name manually with using right click on the project ->refactor->rename

Answer (score 1):

New ADT update is available. Please update both SDK and Ecclipse plugin.